# json.net parsing windows phone

Tags: .net, parsing, windows-phone-7, json.net

I make a request to server and get response

```
    {"response":[{"uid":18186153,"first_name":"Vlad","last_name":"Prylipko","online":0,"lists":[1]},
{"uid":22285147,"first_name":"Max","last_name":"Apro","online":0,"lists":[1]},
{"uid":22532029,"first_name":"Sofi","last_name":"Cei","online":0,"lists":[1]},
```

I'm trying to parse it into listbox(not now, but in future) and I want to get an array with strings like

```
string[] names=["Vlad","Max","Sofi"]
string[] uids=["18186153","22285147","22532029"]
```

Here is my not working code =(.I'm using Json.net for WP7

```
    void c_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
                {
                    lock (this)
                    {


      string xx = e.Result;
                        string result = xx.Substring(13,xx.Length-15);
                       // JOb

ject o = JObject.Parse(xx);

                    Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(result);
                    foreach (string name in values.Keys)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(name);
                    }
                    /*JDi z = JArray.Parse(xx);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                    {

                        var list = z["first_name"][i];
                        // MessageBox.Show(list.ToString());
                        Debug.WriteLine(list.ToString());
                    }
                   /* for (int i = 0; i < o.; i++)
                    {
                        string name = (string)o[i]["first_name"];
                        Debug.WriteLine(name);
                    }*/

                }
```

I know what to do, but don't know how to.
I have a dictionary with key-values and need for each of them collect it into arrays like

```
for(int i=0;i<dictionary.items;i++)
{
    if dictionary.item.key[i]=['first_name']
        string_array_first_names[i]=dictionary.item.key[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < count_friends; i++)
                    {
                        string photo_url = response["response"][i]["photo_medium_rec"].ToString();
                        usr[i].Uid = (int)response["response"][i]["uid"];
                        usr[i].First_Name = response["response"][i]["first_name"].ToString();
                        usr[i].Last_Name = response["response"][i]["last_name"].ToString();
                        usr[i].photo_url = photo_url;
                        lcst[i].bitmp = ImageCacher.ImageCacher.GetCacheImage(photo_url);
                        lcst[i].url = photo_url;
                        usr[i].isonline = Convert.ToBoolean((int)response["response"][i]["online"]);
                    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I find when working with JSON it is always best to create the object structure in code and load it, the substring you are doing is risky and difficult to understand 6 months from now.
From there you can user LINQ to get out whatever arrays or dictionaries you feel you need.

```
string json = e.Result;
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
string[] names = response.Users.Select(d=> d.First_Name).ToArray();
string[] uids = response.Users.Select(d=> d.Uid).ToArray();
Dictionary<string, User> users = response.Users.ToDictionary(d=> d.First_Name);
Dictionary<string, string> usersById = response.Users.ToDictionary(d=> d.Uid, d=> d.First_Name);

public class Response {
  public User[] Users {get; set;}
}

public class User {
  public string Uid {get; set; }
  public string First_Name {get; set; }
  public string Last_Name {get; set; }
  public int Online {get; set; }
  public int[] Lists {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think that second line should be:
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);

Comment: The JSON in the question starts with {"response":[{.. So unless JSON.NET has automatic handling for a response object wrapper then I stand by my code sample. If it does then I will update.

Comment: I have some problems: "Users" is not defined, Dictionary marked as unknown definition(type or namespace not found),

Comment: upd:I have some problems:

 "Users"('object' does not contain a definition for 'Users' and no extension method 'Users' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found, are you missing reference...")

Dictionary marked as unknown definition(type or namespace not found), or if I add "using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;" it says "Error 3 Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey,TValue>' requires 2 type arguments"

Comment: @wsevendays bah, all the generic arguments in my code snippet were being turned into HTML. perhaps that was what the first commenter noticed. See the updated code snippet.

Comment: Thats doesn't works, but I tried to find solution and I've got.

Comment: @Chris Your code is correct. Sorry, I didn't read carefully enough - I was looking at parsing wsevendays 'result' variable, where he had ripped out the 'response' part with substring. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
string json = e.Result;
var response = JObject.Parse(json);

var getcount = response["response"].Children<JObject>();
int count_friends=getcount.Cast<JToken>().Values("uid").Count();
Response rr = new Response();
for (int i = 0; i <count_friends; i++)
{
   // rr.Users.ToDictionary(rr.Users[i].Uid => response["response"][i]["uid"].ToString());
    rr.Users[i].First_Name = response["response"][i]["first_name"].ToString();
   // Debug.WriteLine("OUT: "+(string)response["response"][i]["uid"].ToString());
}
```